# How to get tf.estimator.predict() accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I know that `tf.estimator.evaluate()` returns a dictionary contained fields defined by the `eval_metrics`. Therefore, we can make `evaluate()` return the model accuracy by setting the corresponding field and get the accuracy using `result["accuracy"]`.

However, `tf.estimator.predict()` returns a generator, how can I get the prediction accuracy in a similar way? If I can't, is there any other way I can get the prediction accuracy using `tf.estimator`?

I do want to use `tf.estimator` because it's consistent with other parts of the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can iterate over the prediction generator and compare the outputs to your reference labels. Accuracy would be the number of correct predictions divided by total number of predictions.

Answer (score 0):

something like this might help you: tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=output, labels=y)

source: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28968/get-the-probabilities-of-tensorflow

Comment: A simple explanation to your answer will be great!